# Numerical keyboard quickly closes and open between input fields on Unity

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a mobile project where the user must type the confirmation code from a text message sent through cellphone. The number is made by 4 digits, so I decided to use 4 input fields that when finished editing concatenate the four fields and check if the resulted string is correct.

Currently the problem with this method is that either when the player types a number and the field focus automatically on the next one or when the player clicks on each of the input fields to edit a character, the keyboard automatically closes and reopen. It's very quickly but noticeable.

I've tried the following code on update with no success

```
if (currentScreen == 3) //Scene for code verification
    TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.NumberPad);
```

for some reason focusing on a new input field automatically forces the keyboard to closes, and as soon as I select the new input field, it reopens...

I'm using unity 5.6.1f1 and the error occurs on iOS and Android.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for this problem here:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1075452/ios-touchscreenkeyboard-closes-and-open-when-tappi.html

You could also use one input field and set maximum length to 4 and then get it as a string to use it later, it is better if you don't  want to modify unity solution in the native iOS and Android  codes.

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately the problem with this specific solution you suggested of a single input field is because after I type the verification code I can't edit the specific solution without messing the text. It basically backs off the text is after the character I am editing :( I have a screen similar to this one: https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/two-step5.png?sr=1

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the solution to this exact issue and this post helped me to explore other options and I was able to find a work around.

If you are forcing a selection from one input field to the next, the OnDeselect() method in the input field will force the m_SoftKeyboard to hide if it's not null and will make the keyboard hide before the next selected input field will call it back up. So I created a custom input field script that inherited the TMP_InputField to override this and only have it hide on the last input is complete (AKA the code is complete).

```
public class CustomInputField : TMP_InputField
{
    private CodeParent widget;
    private TouchScreenKeyboard softKeyboard;

    public override void OnDeselect(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        softKeyboard = m_SoftKeyboard;
        m_SoftKeyboard = null;
        base.OnDeselect(eventData);
        m_SoftKeyboard = softKeyboard;


        if (widget.isAllDigitsEntered && m_SoftKeyboard != null)
        {
            m_SoftKeyboard.active = false;
            m_SoftKeyboard = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.